# How to retrieve the location of a control on the view?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a button on a view, I want to add another button next to it when the first button is touched.
Therefore I need it's top left corner to do the math.

Here's what is puzzling me greatly:
// this code is executed when the button is pressed

NSLog(@"X:%f",moreButton.frame.origin.x);

that returns on the first and second click the followings:

2010-04-24 22:58:25.883 iPad PopOver[8095:40b] X:-1.999002
2010-04-24 22:58:25.884 iPad PopOver[8095:40b] Y:0.000000

why and how can I get the x,y of an existing button on the view? (button created via IB)

Thanks!
mE

ps: I have looked at similar posts and my code looks fine but I keep getting zeros (it's an ipad app if matters in any way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following and see if this changes things, your code strictly should work, but I usually use an integer formatter.

```
NSLog(@"X:%d Y%d", moreButton.frame.origin.x, moreButton.frame.origin.y);
```

Once you've cracked that, you also have the following methods you can perform on the button that you may find useful

```
convertPoint:toView:
convertPoint:fromView:
convertRect:toView:
convertRect:fromView:
```

Comment: Coordinates are specified as floats, so the format shouldn't be a problem.  Transforms can make frames appear to have unusual values, so it might be worth using he methods you suggest to get the coords for the window (just use nil).